# How to get rid of the "unsaved" title from the exported agenda document?

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda, customize

When I export the custom agenda view I get this **"unsaved"** text in the exported PDF document (see blow):

**Exported PDF**

[image]

**Agenda-related code in init.el**

```
  (setq org-agenda-exporter-settings
    '((ps-number-of-columns 2)
      (ps-landscape-mode t)
      (org-agenda-add-entry-text-maxlines 5)
      (org-agenda-write-buffer-name "My Agenda (filtered by :@WORK:)")
      (htmlize-output-type 'css)))
  (setq org-agenda-custom-commands
    '(("w" "Work-related tasks"
       ((agenda ""))
       ((ps-number-of-columns 2)
        (org-agenda-span 14)
        (ps-landscape-mode t)
        (org-agenda-prefix-format " [ ] %t ")
        (org-agenda-time-grid nil)
        (org-agenda-show-all-dates t)
        (org-deadline-warning-days 0)
        (org-agenda-with-colors nil)
        (org-agenda-remove-tags t)
        (org-agenda-tag-filter-preset '("+@WORK")))
       ("~/Dropbox/orgfiles/views/work.pdf"))))
```

I tried to remove it by adding this line but to no avail:

```
  (org-agenda-write-buffer-name "My Agenda (filtered by :@WORK:)")
```

What does it mean "unsaved"? Is there any way to replace it correctly?

**Note**

- To have PS (default) exported to PDF you need to have `ps2pdf` tool installed in your system.
- To export the agenda view press `C-c a e`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### What does it mean "unsaved"?

Unsaved is added by ps-print.el when it generates pdfs for unsaved buffers.

#### Is there any way to replace it correctly?

This can be changed by setting org-agenda-exporter-settings:

```
(setq org-agenda-exporter-settings
    '((ps-left-header (list 'org-agenda-write-buffer-name))
      (ps-right-header
           (list "/pagenumberstring load"
                 (lambda () (format-time-string "%d/%m/%Y"))))
      (ps-print-color-p 'black-white)
      (ps-font-size '(12 . 11))       ; Lanscape . Portrait
      (ps-top-margin 55)
      (ps-left-margin 35)
      (ps-right-margin 30)))
```

You can find further info on these and other options in ps-print.el (it has informative comments on interface, usage, setting layouts, etc at the beginning of the file).

I advice you to change org-agenda-write-buffer-name to org-agenda-custom-commands so as to give meaningful names per command. The way to achieve this would be in these lines:

```
(setq org-agenda-exporter-settings
  '((ps-left-header (list 'org-agenda-write-buffer-name))
    (ps-right-header
          (list "/pagenumberstring load"
                (lambda () (format-time-string "%d/%m/%Y"))))
    (ps-number-of-columns 2)
    (ps-landscape-mode t)
    (org-agenda-add-entry-text-maxlines 5)
    (htmlize-output-type 'css)))
(setq org-agenda-custom-commands
  '(("w" "Work-related tasks"
    ((agenda ""))
    ((org-agenda-span 14)
    (org-agenda-prefix-format " [ ] %t ")
    (org-agenda-time-grid nil)
    (org-agenda-show-all-dates t)
    (org-deadline-warning-days 0)
    (org-agenda-with-colors nil)
    (org-agenda-remove-tags t)
    (org-agenda-tag-filter-preset '("+@WORK"))
    (org-agenda-write-buffer-name "My Agenda (filtered by :@WORK:)"))
   ("~/Dropbox/orgfiles/views/work.pdf"))))
```

HTH